# tsql How do I find a surname in a string of text

Tags: t-sql

How do I find a match in a string of text.

For example. I have a surname of "Smith" in Col1.

I have a group name of "Mr A B Smith and Mrs J Bike" in Col2.

How do I search the group name to find the match of "Smith"?

The group name is manually entered into  the CRM system in the above format so I cannot change this.

Thanks

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a combination of `CASE` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(Col1, Col2, 0) > 0
            THEN 'Exists'
        ELSE 'Not Exists'
    END [Does Col1 Exist in Col2]
FROM Table
```

or a combination of `CASE` and `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(COL2) > LEN(REPLACE(COL2, COL1, ''))
            THEN 'Exists'
        ELSE 'Not Exists'
    END [Does Col1 Exist in Col2]
FROM Table
```

or, if you want just the results where the value in Col1 exists in Col2 then:

```
SELECT
    Col1
    , Col2
FROM Table
WHERE LEN(COL2) > LEN(REPLACE(COL2, COL1, ''))
```

Comment: Hi, the second statement kind of works but the issue is that it brings back "exists" if any of the text is matched. So for example if I type just the letter "m" it says exists because of the "Mr". If I type say a "Z" it does not exist.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem with the statement? It's correct, based on your request. Maybe you have additional conditions / rules which you haven't posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the Smiths in Col2 you could use the percent sign and LIKE keyword to search for substrings:

```
SELECT Col2
FROM [TABLENAME]
WHERE Col2 LIKE '%Smith%'
```

Comment: Hi, I would need to validate that the data held in col1 matches any part of the string in col2, so don't see how that would work?